# Zoom or move to specific pixel co-ordindates in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I need to either move to or preferably zoom to pixel level, but I want to zoom to the specified co-ordinates in pixels.

For example: 100, 200 it should zoom center to pixel level or specified level of zoom.

I'm assuming such a simple feature is hiding somewhere in Photoshop (I am working with CS5).

Comment: I do not believe that option exists

Comment: I am aware of that although Photoshop has nothing to do with programming? But it is included in the tag list, so I assumed it was covered here.

Answer (score 0):

No, such a feature does not exist in Photoshop.

Alternatives include:

- Zoom in/scroll over by hand using the Ruler as a guide (CTRL - R to see the Ruler)
- Use the navigator window to scroll via a thumbnail

Hope that helps.